# Acer Bluetooth is not recognized by Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, acer

I upgraded from Windows 10 to Ubuntu 18.04, my product (ACER E5-573G-74Q5) was working, but now my Bluetooth is not being recognized by Ubuntu, I've already installed `bluez` and `bluez-tools`, but the Bluetooth still missed

I executed a command called `rfkill` and it lists the devices bellow:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

It say that the hardware is not blocked. What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: try this https://askubuntu.com/questions/1341128/bluetooth-headphone-mic-not-detected-issues-with-audio-quality-headphone-speake/1341129#1341129