# Bluetooth Headphone Mic not detected. Issues with Audio quality Headphone speaker With solved Answer

Tags: bluetooth, microphone, headphones

My laptop is Acer and I have Bluetooth 5.0 Headphone. My Headphone mic doesn't detected and Headphone speaker audio quality is not good. I have tried lots of drivers bluez, pulseaudio, ofono, phonesim. All are not working for me and have issues with them and then I found a thread in Askubuntu. [Failed to change profile to headset_head_unit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/831331/failed-to-change-profile-to-headset-head-unit/1340778#1340778)
This thread tell me how to solve this issue. I un installed all the old drivers and then installed Pipewire. Follow this steps maybe helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Open your terminal and follow these steps:

1. We will use a PPA for adding Pipewire to Ubuntu 20.04, which is maintained regularly:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pipewire-debian/pipewire-upstream
   ```
2. To update the PPA packages in your system do:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```
3. Install the package:

   ```
   sudo apt install pipewire
   ```
4. There is also a dependency needed to be installed with Pipewire, otherwise you will face the issue of "Bluetooth headset won't connect after installing pipewire". Install the dependency by:

   ```
   sudo apt install libspa-0.2-bluetooth
   ```
5. Now, to install the client libraries:

   ```
   sudo apt install pipewire-audio-client-libraries
   ```
6. Reload the daemon:

   ```
   systemctl --user daemon-reload
   ```
7. Remove your paired Headphones from your paired list
8. Then Reboot your machine
9. You can ensure that Pipewire is now running through:

   ```
   pactl info
   ```

   This command will give the following output, in Server Name you can see:

   ```
   PulseAudio (on PipeWire 0.3.28)
   ```
10. Now you have pair your Headphones your machine
11. If Reboot needed reboot your machine again (mostly needed)

Now you can enjoy better audio quality.

When you need to use your headphone microphone, you have change to change it manually.

Note: This may be a little tricky and occasionally buggy, but you should have better audio quality, though microphone audio still needs some improvement.